# Group values in json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "PMID": {
    "0": 31920716.0,
    "1": 31915546.0,
    "2": 31912059.0,
    "3": 31908815.0
},
"ArticleTitle": {
    "0": "Clinical Usefulness of Computational Modeling-Guided Persistent Atrial Fibrillation Ablation: Updated Outcome of Multicenter Randomized Study.",
    "1": "Prevalence and Progression of Cognitive Impairment in Atrial Fibrillation Patients after Treatment with Catheter Ablation or Drug Therapy.",
    "2": "Non traumatic spinal epidural haematoma.",
    "3": "Twelve-month outcome in patients with stroke and atrial fibrillation not suitable to oral anticoagulant strategy: the WATCH-AF registry."
},
 "Authors": {
    "0": [
      "Kim IS",
      "Uhm JS",
    ],
    "1": [
      "Ortak J",
      "Caglayan E"
    ],
    "2": [
      "Khalid NA",
      "Shah N"
    ],
    "3": [
      "Nighoghossian N",
      "Amarenco P"
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to group values in this way:

```
{
"0": {
       "PMID": 31920716.0,
       "ArticleTitle": "Clinical Usefulness of Computational Modeling-Guided Persistent Atrial Fibrillation Ablation: Updated Outcome of Multicenter Randomized Study.",
       "Authors" : [
      "Kim IS",
      "Uhm JS",
    ],
}
```

and so on, by the position in the dictionary in order to obtain an item with all the indexes grouped.
Is there a function to do this operation in Python?

Comment: I like to remind everyone who asks questions like this about JSON that the question need not really be about JSON--Instead, as you can see in the answer given, it's a question of manipulating the "native" data structures in Python that JSON deserializes to/serializes from.  Removing JSON from the question might help in the future, when you go looking for answers :-)

Comment: `{k: dict(i) for k, i in groupby(sorted(([n, i, k] for n, g in d.items() for k, i in g.items()), key=itemgetter(-1)), list.pop)}` [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and keep updating in the order you like to keep it . The following code explains it

```py
def pack_ordinal(data):
    result = dict()
    for i in data:
        for j in data[i]:
            result[j] = result.get(j, dict())
            result[j][i] = data[i][j]
    return result
```

Comment: It's more common to iterate over key-value pairs: `for k, v in data.items()`, `for k_i, v_i in v.items()`. Also you can use `defaultdict` and bypass dict initialization `result = defaultdict(dict)`. All together it will make code a bit cleaner *(imho)*. [Code](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsJADEX3/YosWxA3bkTwS0opwzwwzCNDmhb8@jGVooJZBMI9h5v6lAeVy7Vya4Epg6WUvBWksgDmSizgfDBrEodWuk4PqMbGmdhhMal3Rsxw60CH/aIc3H@Nfl/DOw7EEE@wARbYrTOKz0t/yB9iRmVm3KntH/n2jEpOY5y0T/HjAVm5HHlrLw).